# VB.net Memory efficient function needed

Tags: .net, performance, arraylist, memory-management, string-concatenation

I'm getting out of memory exceptions from the following function when RowCollection is 50000+ and thus i need to make it more memory efficient. The function is simply needs to construct a comma separated string of the row indexes stored in RowCollection. Can anyone spot any obvious memory hungry operations in the following?

N.B RowCollection just contains a list of row indexes stored as integers.

```
 Private Function GetCommaSeparatedString(ByRef RowIndexes As ArrayList) As String
        Dim RowString As String = String.Empty

        'Build a string of the row indexes 
        'Add one onto each index value so our indexes begin at 1 
        For Each Row In RowIndexes 
            RowString += CInt(Row.ToString) + 1 & ","
        Next

        'Remove the last comma
        If RowString.Length > 0 Then
            RowString = RowString.Substring(0, RowString.Length - 1)
        End If

        Return RowString
    End Function
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The correct spelling is "separated".

Comment: On a side note, why `ArrayList`? This looks like a job for `List<int>`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure why you're getting out of memory errors, unless the string representation of your rows is extremely large, because you never have more than one or two non-garbage-collectible strings.

However, your method *is* horribly inefficient because it spends so much time copying the contents of half-built strings. A StringBuilder is more appropriate when building large strings, because it can be modified without re-creating the contents each time.

HOWEVER, in this case even a StringBuilder is a bad idea, because you are joining strings and there is already a method to do that: String.Join. Just use a LINQ query to do the add-one-to-index-stuff and you get a one-liner:

```
Private Function GetCommaSeparatedString(ByVal RowIndexes As ArrayList) As String
    Return String.Join(",", From index In RowIndexes Select CInt(index) + 1)
End Function
```

I would also recommend not passing by reference unless you actually need it. You aren't modifying RowIndexes, so pass it by value. I'm also not sure why you are ToString()-ing the index then immediately parsing it. Aren't they already integers? Just use CInt.

Comment: I agree with you completely, although I probably would stream it out if possible to redesign the code using this method.

Comment: @PhilipRieck What do you mean by 'stream it out'?

Comment: @Strilanc either create an IEnumerable<string> method to get lines, or read it through a textreader that appends commas, etc - that is, not try to process the entire file from memory at one time.

Comment: @Strilanc 
Thanks for all the comments so far...

I can't stream the result, so using a string builder or String.Join seems the best method. What does the above line become with Option Strict On? I've yet to get my head around using Linq. Thanks

Comment: You should always have Option Strict On. Really understanding the line requires understanding linq, so look that up. The line gives String.Join an IEnumerable which enumerates the results of adding 1 to the items in RowIndexes. String.Join applies ToString to each enumerated element, using a StringBuilder to append them together with the separator.

Answer (score 3):

**Update**: while this is a straight change to use stringbuilder, look at the better approaches by [Strilanc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3610800/vb-net-memory-efficient-function-needed/3611324#3611324) or [Steven Sudit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3610800/vb-net-memory-efficient-function-needed/3610894#3610894)

Well, you may still run out of memory (memory *is* finite, after all), but you should be using a StringBuilder, not concatenating strings.  Each time, you are creating a new string object rather than changing it (As strings are immutable)

```
Private Function GetCommaSeparatedString(ByRef RowIndexes As ArrayList) As String
    Dim RowString As New StringBuilder()

    'Build a string of the row indexes 
    'Add one onto each index value so our indexes begin at 1 
    For Each Row In RowIndexes 
        RowString.AppendFormat("{0},",  CInt(Row.ToString) + 1)
    Next

    'Remove the last comma
    If RowString.Length > 0 Then
        RowString.Append(RowString.Substring(0, RowString.Length - 1))
    End If

    Return RowString
End Function
```

Comment: @Steven Sudit Has the answer I would go with - stream it, or create and throw away each row as you need it.  I can't immediately think of a valid design that should requires the entire contents as a string.

Answer (score 2):

`StringBuilder` is a good idea, but why not just avoid the problem by streaming the output out instead of trying to hold it all in memory at once?

Answer (score 1):

This is because in each iteration, behind the scenes you are creating 2 strings, and they are getting big nearer the end.

"1,2,3,4,5,....499,500"
"1,2,3,4,5,....499,500,"

at the end of only 500 iterations, you are creating 2 strings nearly 2000 characters long, only to have them discarded in the next iteration (but the runtime may be keeping them around).  
In the last iteration, your string (from 1 to 50000) would be 100,000 characters long, assuming your row indexes are even sequential.  This would mean you have allocated ~ 10,000,000,000 characters or (I believe 2 bytes/char) 20 gigabytes of strings.

You can start by using `StringBuilder` instead of `+=` on a string (RowString).
**Ex**

```
Dim RowString As StringBuilder = new StringBuilder( 100000 )

For Each Row In RowIndexes 
    RowString.Append( CInt(Row.ToString) + 1).Append( "," )
Next

'...'

Return RowString.ToString
```

You can try the next one as well, but you should profile the two and pick the best for you.

```
Private Function GetCommaSeperatedString(ByRef RowIndexes As ArrayList) As String
    Dim indexArray as String[] = RowIndexes
                                 .Select(Function(r)=> (CInt(r.ToString) + 1)ToString)
                                 .ToArray
    return String.Join( ',', indexArray)
End Function
```

* note: these are the first lines of VB I've ever written, so I may have made a basic mistake (especially in the linq/lambda stuff), but the point is there.